# HTML fails in Qt QLabel

Tags: c++, html, qt, qlabel

When using a QLabel element filled with some html text, I have a problem: it does not simply render the HTML, it inserts some space around the html text.

The following renders ok:

```
A simple text!
```

The following fails:

```
A <strong>HTML</strong> text!
```

Actually, Qt renders everything okay, but always I have html in my text, there are some space around my text, however, in my application, this space becomes a real problem. All CSS I've tried fails, maybe I just do not know the exactly way to style it.

Comment: First of all you should know that QLabel supports *richText* formatting. This not the same as Html. RichText is only subset of html. See http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/richtext-html-subset.html. But strong tag is supported by QLabel. May be you are missing something in your description.

Comment: Actually I know it just supports rich text, anyway, the error still occurs.

Answer (score 5):

Are you setting the text using [setText()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html#text-prop) function? If you pass a `QString` which contains rich text in `setText()` parameter, the rich text is supposed to be rendered. If not, you can try to set the `QLabel`'s [textFormat](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop) to `Qt::RichText`.

Comment: @Krish I think I was not able to expose the idea as I want: Everything works, the label is displayed. However, when using rich text, looks like Qt creates a padding within the QLabel.

Comment: @Wanderson: can you please post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this code and it's working.

```
   #include <QApplication>
    #include <QLabel>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("<strong>Hello</strong> "
    "<font color=red>Wanderson !");
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
    }
```

[image]